# Can we use Linux Mint ISO to repair Ubuntu's Grub?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, grub, system-recovery

A friend of mine is running Ubuntu and got `GRUB RESCUE`. Can they use Mint ISO to repair their Grub? As I don't have Ubuntu ISO?

Comment: I guess yes, you can checkout this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/reinstall-grub-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the Ubuntu installation is still present (and only GRUB was lost), sure, you can use any distro that has live booting to do so. `chroot` into the Ubuntu installation and install and update Grub. If `/dev/sda5` is the Ubuntu partition:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/sys
mount -t devpts none /mnt/dev/pts
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
#Inside the chroot
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
# Unmount all those mounts:
for m in /mnt/{dev/pts,dev,proc,sys,}; do umount $m; done
# reboot
```

If all you need to do is install grub, and updating isn't necessary, then you don't need the `chroot`:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

If you have a separate boot partition, remember to mount it as well, after mounting `/mnt`.

Answer (score 0):

Since grub is standard boot loader, you can use any distro that uses grub as its bootloader.